# Easy Modal Height Issue

Tags: wordpress, css

I am using easy modal plugin for my wordpress site. The modal works fine but there is only one issue that the height of the modal sets itself to the end scroll of the page. The width is set to 80% which works fine but the `height:auto` property is not working fine at all. Kindly let me know how can i fix this issue? . If in the following CSS I hard code the height then the trick works but all I am trying is to achieve the height:auto property.

```
.modal {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    display: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto !important;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40%;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 1.25em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like expected behavior to me. Can you set an explicit height? I see that there's a setting for that in the admin panel (demo/demo): http://easy-modal.com/demo/wp-admin/admin.php?page=easy-modal&modal_id=1#top#options I'm not sure why you'd use CSS.

Comment: @isherwood i got the issue its happening because of css from twitterbootstrap due to `bottom: 0` , Is there a way I can set `bottom:none` for `.modal` class?

Comment: Sure, though 'none' isn't a valid value for bottom. You can do 'auto' or 'inherit'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the font-size:16px to default font-size:14px, it will resolve the issue.